# Как сделать joinwith с одной таблицей дважды - yii2

Tags: yii2

Нужно связать две таблицы:

1. 'bills': id и name (названия счетов)
2. 'money': bill_id_from, bill_id_to, summa (с какого на какой счет был перевод)

Мне нужно получить имена счетов, но yii2 не хочет давать мне имена сразу для двух полей. Как я понимаю, в моделе нужен метод типа:

```
public function getBills()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Bills::className(), [
        'id' => 'bill_id_from ', 'id' => 'bill_id_to'
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Написать JOIN дважды с таблицей money.привожу пример в виде скл (SLECT m1.name AS name_from,m1.bill_id_to AS nam_to  FROM bills b INNER JOIN money m1 ON b.id = m1.bill_id_from INNER JOIN money m2 ON b.id = m2.bill_id_to)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создаете 2 связи, а потом ->joinWith('billsFrom AS billsFrom')->joinWith('billsTo AS billsTo'), т.е. названия рилейшнов не являются алиасами. Можете продампать $query->createCommand()->getRawSql() и увидите все сами

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно 2 связи:

```
public function getBillFrom()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Bills::className(), ['id' => 'bill_id_from']);
}

public function getBillTo()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Bills::className(), ['id' => 'bill_id_to']);
}
```

Теперь можно брать информацию по обоим счетам:

```
$money->billFrom->name;
$money->billTo->name;
```

Comment: `$res= Money::find()->joinWith('billTo')->joinWith('billFrom')->all();`
**Ругается** - Not unique table/alias: 'bills'